# C# - ASP.NET - REST API - Querying In Controller

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, rest

I am attempting to follow this tutorial here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

To get a REST API set up for a website I am working on. I've never made anything with ASP.NET before so some stuff is throwing me off. I've made it to here (with changes in the models):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using DashBoardWidgets.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DashBoardWidgets.Controllers
{
    public class BoilerReadingsController : ApiController
    {
        public BoilerReading ExecuteQuery()
        {
            var MyBoilerReading = new BoilerReading();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=DNN;User ID=sa;Password=*****;");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from DNN.dbo.avtActionForm_BoilerReadingsLog order by TimeStamp", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DateTime TimeStamp_q = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["TimeStamp"];
                int TurbineChosen_q = (int)dt.Rows[0]["TurbineChosen"];
                decimal MOPSuctionPressure_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["MOPSuctionPressure"];
                decimal LubeOilPressure_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["LubeOilPressure"];
                decimal ControlOilPressure_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["ControlOilPressure"];
                decimal LubeOilTemp_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["LubeOilTemp"];
                decimal BRNOilTemp1_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["BRNOilTemp1"];
                decimal TBDRNOilTempFront_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["TBDRNOilTempFront"];
                decimal TBDRNOilTempRear_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["TBDRNOilTempRear"];
                decimal BRNOilTemp2_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["BRNOilTemp2"];
                decimal BRNOilTemp3_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["BRNOilTemp3"];
                decimal BRNOilTemp4_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["BRNOilTemp4"];
                decimal BRNOilTemp5_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["BRNOilTemp5"];
                decimal BRNOilTemp6_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["BRNOilTemp6"];
                decimal BRNOilTemp7_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["BRNOilTemp7"];
                decimal SealOilPressureExciteEnd_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["SealOilPressureExciteEnd"];
                decimal SealOilPressureTurbineEnd_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["SealOilPressureTurbineEnd"];
                string Username_q = dt.Rows[0]["Username"].ToString();
                int Index_q = (int)dt.Rows[0]["Index"];
                new BoilerReading { TimeStamp = TimeStamp_q, TurbineChosen = TurbineChosen_q, MOPSuctionPressure = MOPSuctionPressure_q, LubeOilTemp = LubeOilTemp_q, ControlOilPressure = ControlOilPressure_q, BRNOilTemp1 = BRNOilTemp1_q, TBDRNOilTempFront = TBDRNOilTempFront_q, TBDRNOilTempRear = TBDRNOilTempRear_q, BRNOilTemp2 = BRNOilTemp2_q, BRNOilTemp3 = BRNOilTemp3_q, BRNOilTemp4 = BRNOilTemp4_q, BRNOilTemp5 = BRNOilTemp5_q, BRNOilTemp6 = BRNOilTemp6_q, BRNOilTemp7 = BRNOilTemp7_q, SealOilPressureExciteEnd = SealOilPressureExciteEnd_q, SealOilPressureTurbineEnd = SealOilPressureTurbineEnd_q, Username = Username_q, Index = Index_q };
            }

            connection.Close();
            return BoilerReading;           
        }

        BoilerReading[] BoilerReadings = new BoilerReading[]
        {
            new BoilerReading { TimeStamp = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
         };

        public IEnumerable<BoilerReading> GetAllBoilerReadings()
        {
            return BoilerReadings;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult BoilerReading(int id)
        {
            var BoilerReading = BoilerReadings.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (BoilerReading == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(BoilerReading);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to replace the static arrays with the query I have in the ExecuteQuery() function, but I can't figure it out. I've tried a few different ways. I've tried adding the code to query directly into the array parts and changing the variables, but the compiler doesn't seem to like them there. Whenever I try calling ExecuteQuery(); and passing the queried data it doesn't work.

What is the proper way to replace these arrays with queried data so that it is dynamic?

With a dynamic query from a SQL server.

Comment: Some tips to get you started: Your question is how to fill arrays from query, the stuff about REST and asp.net is distracting. If you really only always want `TOP 1` then you don't need an array, you just need a `BoilerReading`, possibly as a property. Use the same syntax (`new BoilerReading {...`) to assign values from `dt.Rows[0]["whatever"]`.

Comment: I've tried that, but I guess I don't understand how the REST API will be able to get that boiler reading. Will the IEnumerable<BoilerReading> GetAllBoilerReadings() still work if I put the new boiler reading inside of the ExecuteQuery()? I've updated my code to show this. ALso when I try it like this I get 'Cannot convert method group 'BoilerReading' to non-delegate type 'BoilerReading', so it doesn't run.

Comment: The `BoilerReading` method implies you want to return one item. What is `GetAllBoilerReadings()` for? Do you want one, or all? And don't name a method the same as a class. So instead of `BoilerReading(int id)`, use just `Get` or `GetBoilerReading`.

Comment: Yes, for now my query is to return the top 1, but I want to future proof it in case the number of records I am bringing back needs to change at some point in the future. On top of that I'd like to understand the flow of the program over all instead of just shoving everything into an edge case to meet what I need this one single time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't name your method the same as a class.

Second, you have a method that returns a `BoilerReading`, just call it.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetBoilerReading(int id)
{
     var BoilerReading = ExecuteQuery(); //you will probably want this to take an int parameter and add a WHERE clause to your query.
     if (BoilerReading == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }
     return Ok(BoilerReading);
 }
```

Now fix up ExecuteQuery so it actually returns a `BoilerReading` instance:

```
public BoilerReading ExecuteQuery()
{
    var MyBoilerReading = new BoilerReading();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=DNN;User ID=sa;Password=*****;");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from DNN.dbo.avtActionForm_BoilerReadingsLog order by TimeStamp", connection);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DateTime TimeStamp_q = (DateTime)dt.Rows[0]["TimeStamp"];
        int TurbineChosen_q = (int)dt.Rows[0]["TurbineChosen"];
        decimal MOPSuctionPressure_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["MOPSuctionPressure"];
        decimal LubeOilPressure_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["LubeOilPressure"];
        decimal ControlOilPressure_q = (decimal)dt.Rows[0]["ControlOilPressure"];
        .... etc.
        MyBoilerReading.Timestamp = TimeStamp_q;
        MyBoilerReading.TurbineChosen = TurbineChosen_q;
        ... etc.    
    }

    connection.Close();
    return MyBoilerReading; //return the instance that you actually populate with values.      
}
```

Note that I am not promoting this as good design. You will need more robust error and null checking. You are also using resources (Connections, Commands, etc.) that should be `Disposed`.